# SFMC Journey - Remainder Contacts

Tags: marketing-cloud, journeybuilder

I don't know why this isn't already incorporated into Marketing Cloud, but...

When you have a decision split in a journey, some of your contacts may be False and go down the Remainder leg and there's no built-in way of finding out who those contacts were.

Does anyone have any suggestions on how they track Remainder contacts? I'm updating some journeys and I'd like to incorporate them in the future.

Thank you!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use the Update Contact activity to log which contacts go through the Remainder branch:

> Use the update contact activity to modify a contact attribute value
> when a contact reaches this activity in a journey. You choose a
> sendable data extension and set a static value that overwrites this
> value for each contact that reaches the activity. If no rows for the
> associated Contact Key exist, a new row is added.

Add this activity right after the split, on the Remainder branch, and select a Data Extension where you would like to log this info. You can either use an existing Data Extension, or create a brand new one just for this use case - that way you’ll be able to easily access information about Contacts who went through this specific branch.

If you’re expecting large volumes of contacts to go through the journey, you can add a retention policy to this DE, eg. to only keep one week or one month of data.

For more, see here: https://help.salesforce.com/apex/HTViewHelpDoc?id=sf.mc_jb_update_a_contact.htm&language=en_US

Comment: Thank you very much for this. I'll create a folder of DEs and put them in that. Still, it would be sooooo much easier if Salesforce would just count the number of remainders.

Answer (score 0):

Zuzanna's recommendation would be the best solution and here's a great reference on how to use "data binding" in the Update Contact activity to populate the fields in the data extension: https://sfmc.quest/sfmctipsandtrickschallenge/

Here are two other ideas to consider depending on your use case:

Campaign member activity - If your journey is part of a campaign you can update the contact's campaign member status in the campaign with this object added to the remainder path.  You'll need the campaign member ID if you aren't using a Salesforce Data Entry Event.

Object Activity - Update a field in the Contact using the Object Activity.  Either create a new field on the Contact object or leverage a field like "Comments" to update each contact in CRM.

Comment: Thanks, Tim! I'll use this to keep track.